Синонимизировать метки на тему [хосты]
Предлагаю сделать следующие синонимизации:

hosting (161) -> хостинг (414) (она на русском) -- описания у обеих есть;
hosts (48) и хост (5) -> хосты (3) (она на русском и Метки: множественное или единственное число?) -- описания ни у одной нет - нужно сделать.


hosts может подразумевать вполне конкретный файл с именем hosts, переводить его на русский будет немножко странно

+1 за синонимизацию hosting и хостинг , но против 2го пункта - согласна с комментом, что hosts может быть конкретным файлом. Максимум синонимизация хост и хосты

Этот вопрос похож на: Синонимизация меток [хостинг] и [hosting]. Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.

Заменил во всех вопросах [tag:хосты] на [tag:хост].

@Зонтик, так надо было наоборот...
